# Decoding Mapbox grid response

Tags: vector, mapbox

Can anybody give me insight into the grid JSON structure that Mapbox returns for use with overlays on tiles.  What is the significance of !,#,$?

[image: Screenshot from HTTP Proxy of Mapbox .grid.json response]

Comment: It is documented here... https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec/blob/master/1.3/utfgrid.md

Comment: Awesome thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Can you convert that to an answer, and close out this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A current version of MapBox's utfgrid spec can be located in MapBox's [Github repository.](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec/blob/master/1.3/utfgrid.md) For a more general overview, please see https://www.mapbox.com/developers/utfgrid/